# Referring to a cell in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

I am trying to refer to a particular cell in my file (month) so that every month all I need to do change that value and refresh the file without fiddling in the backend.

I have an ODBC link to our database and am using SQL statements to generate my data. I have figured out the majority of the syntax required but now I am stumped with this error:

[image]

Invalid period selected. As you can see it is a perfect copy of whats in the Period column.

Is there anyone that can help?

Alternatively, is there a better way to refer to a cell from the SQL statements?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Jason. Have you tried separating `*` symbol with spaces? `select * from` instead of `select*from`

Comment: Referring to one cell in SQL syntax is SELECT * FROM [SHEET-NAME$A1]; and to range SELECT * FROM [SHEET-NAME$A1:C7]; or column  SELECT * FROM [SHEET-NAME$J:J;

Comment: @Neykuratick - doesn't matter, power query will insert the spaces.

Comment: @xShen - inserted [Control$A2], but still results in same error "Invalid Period selected".